# Virto Commerce Not able to add Quote Functionality in B2B theme

Tags: virtocommerce

Iam evaluating the Virto commerce platform from my local machine. When i installed B2B theme it is seeing that the request for quote is not listed in landing page or in product tab. Is there any way to get this done? i had tried and enabled in store settings. Iam using Electronics catalog as sample data.

Screenshot of Product Page
[Product Page (No add to quote button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLaAN.png)

Landing Page of B2B
[B2B Landing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pu6B.png)

**Iam looking for something similar to below Two Images**

[Landing Page of Electronics with Quote Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T66z.png)

Also in product page like this 
[Product Page with Add to Quote (ELectronics)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glhtV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The B2B theme is still under development therefore not all the functions that you might see in the Electronics theme are present here. Requests for quotation  is one of the functions not implemented yet for that theme.

Comment: Thanks tatarincev.  I would also like to point another issue i saw in electronics theme. I had requested quote for 3 products  but when i go to my quotes page in my account, it is saying " You haven't submitted any quote requests yet" (Url: http://localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/quoterequest/#/) this is the url coming when i go to my account and got to the quotes tab. Then when i changed the url manually to  http://localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/account/quoterequests, all the submitted quotes are visible with RFQ link for accept or reject.

Comment: Where'd you get  this wrong link?  localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/quoterequest/#?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response, My profile Link is http://localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/account#/profile, further when i clicked the Quote Request Button inside my profile along with other options like subscriptions, order, Your list, Change password etc will redirect to new url http://localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/account#/quotes. and when i click on Quote button located on right hand side top of the page iam redirecting to http://localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/quoterequest/#/

Comment: All seems ok, is a right behavior localhost/storefront/Electronics/en-US/quoterequest/#  url should display your current quote just like it is done fto see a  current shopping cart.

Comment: Yes, but i dont have any option to see my submitted quotes and received proposals.

Comment: All your historical quotes you can see in your customer cabinet. Click on your account name in top right corner -> Quote Requests